# Добавление списка со случайным количеством элементов в список списков

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

Возникла необходимость добавить 35 листов `cars` (с рандомным количеством экземпляров) в новый `listOfCars`. После чего сделать сортировку по количеству этих самых экземпляров.

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    cars.add(new Car(a));
}
ArrayList <ArrayList> listsOfCars = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    listsOfCars.add(cars);
}
Collections.sort(listsOfCars, SizeComparator);
System.out.println(cars);
System.out.println(listsOfCars);
```

Comparator:

```
public static Comparator<ArrayList> SizeComparator = new Comparator<ArrayList>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList arrlist1, ArrayList arrlist2) {
        return arrlist1.size() - arrlist2.size();
    }
};
```

В этом коде проблемы нет, т.к. я вернул его в тот вид, в котором он работает. Но тут у меня создается один лист `cars` с рандомным количеством экземпляров, после чего я его добавляю 35 раз в лист `listsOfCars`. А вот 35 разных листов с рандомным количеством экземпляров добавить не получается. Прошу указать верный путь.

Comment: В этом коде проблемы нет, тк я вернул его в тот вид который работает. Но тут у меня создается один лист cars с рандомным количеством экземпляров, а после чего я его добавляю 35 раз в лист listsOfCars.
А вот 35 разных листов с рандомным количеством экземпляров добавить не получается.И чувство, что я окончательно запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавайте новый список (`cars`) на каждой из 35 итераций со случайным количеством (`count`) элементов в нём:

```
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Car>> listsOfCars = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    int count = rand.nextInt(100);
    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        cars.add(new Car(j));
    }
    listsOfCars.add(cars);
}
Collections.sort(listsOfCars, SizeComparator);
for (ArrayList<Car> cars : listsOfCars)
{
    System.out.print(cars.size() + " ");
}
```

Каковы ограничения на размер списка - не знаю, я взял "от 0 до 99 элементов".

Answer (score 1):

Видимо это то, что вам нужно:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList<Car>> listsOfCars = new ArrayList();
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min

    for (int j = 0; j < randomInt; j++){
        cars.add(new Car(j));
    }

    listsOfCars.add(cars);
}
```

То есть вы создаете цикл с 35 итерациями и уже в нём создаете лист, генерируете случайное число, которое будет определять, сколько будет добавлено машин в него. И уже этот лист добавляете в родителя.

`max` и `min` соответственно определяют границы рандома

Answer (score 1):

Приведу простой пример, подобный Вашему:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();

Random random = new Random();

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    int size = random.nextInt(10);
    arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<>(size));
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++) {
        arrayLists.get(i).add(j);
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<arrayLists.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayLists.get(i).toString());
}

Collections.sort(arrayLists, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {
        return o1.size() - o2.size();
    }
});

System.out.println("---");

for (int i=0; i<arrayLists.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayLists.get(i).toString());
}
```

Здесь сначала создается `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, затем он заполняется случайными (по размеру) `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Далее `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` выводится на консоль, сортируется и выводится снова.

PS: Вот так делать плохо:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> listsOfCars = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

А вот так – хорошо:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Car>> listsOfCars = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 35;

    List<List<Car>> listOfCarList = new ArrayList<>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int size = random.nextInt(1_00);
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(size);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            cars.add(new Car());

        listOfCarList.add(cars);
    }

    listOfCarList
                .stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.size() - e2.size())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```